# Set external ID of a ManyToOne relation without getting the object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using SF2 and Doctrine2.

I have an Entity `Wheel` which have a ManyToOne relationship with the Entity `Car`.

I want to do something like this in a service:

```
$car_id = 1;
$wheel = new Wheel();
$wheel->setCarId($car_id);
```

In other terms, I want to be able to link `Wheel` and `Car` just by using Car's id, without getting the full object (because I don't need it: I only need only the id and I already have it).

How can I do that?

Comment: You really shouldn't. An ORM deals with objects. You add objects to other objects and if you do lazy loading the properties will only be fetched from the DB once requested. If you want to use an ORM, don't program as if it was just another sql database.

Answer (score 13):

Get a reference to the car

```
$carReference = $entityManager->getReference('MyBundle:Car',$carId);
$wheel->setCar($carReference);
```

Keep in mind that the O in ORM stands for Object.  Try to get out of the habit of thinking about database table id's.

Comment: Very interesting, does this solution makes a request to the SQL server ?

Comment: Nope.  Doctrine assumes you use a valid carId.